# Please pay attention to our camera

Tags: transcription

What's the appropriate wording for an emcee at an occasion to ask people on stage to look at the camera for a group photo?  Is it good to say "please pay attention to our camera"?

Comment: I think it would be usual for people to just say "Please look at the camera". "Pay attention to", doesn't sound particularly natural

Comment: How about "please draw your attention to our camera"?

Comment: I almost edited my answer to say that. That works just as well

Comment: I think attention is a red herring here. Even *draw your attention to the camera* does not imply you need to pose for a group photo. It simply asks you to note that the camera exists. Unless it's not obvious where the camera is, *Could everyone smile for the camera?* would certainly be idiomatic. This makes it clear a photo is being taken.

Comment: SAY CHEESE!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

"...  to ask people on stage to look at the camera ..."

Then say "please look at the camera", you shouldn't be using the noun "attention", as you are not asking for attention to the camera, you are asking people to pose for a photo.

"Please smile for the camera" is also fine, but usually it would go something like

> Okay everybody, everybody, um, could you all look this way, yes, thanks, um, we'd just like to get a photo with you all in, okay great, now, er, shuffle up a bit, right, aunty sue could you duck down a bit, we can't see uncle Derek, now er, ok everybody, looking at the camera, say cheese!"

Because actual language is like that.